# Can these IO functions be done another way?

Tags: c++

So, I'm working with C++ Primer, 5th Edition. I'm on section 7.1.3, but since many won't have the book, here's the bottom line of it: the writers are writing code for a book transaction class, and want to implement a read and a print function to respectively take in data for a book and then print it. Here are the book's functions:

```
// input transactions contain ISBN, number of copies sold, and sales price
istream &read(istream &is, Sales_data &item)
{
double price = 0;
is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;
item.revenue = price * item.units_sold;
return is;
}

ostream &print(ostream &os, const Sales_data &item)
{
os <<item.isbn() << " " << item.units_sold << " "
   << item.revenue << " " << item.avg_price();
return os;
}
```

What baffles me a bit is why they get into the hassle of actually passing around IO objects. If I were asked to write such a function myself, I would do it like this:

```
void read()
{
cout << "Please input book number, units sold and price.";
cin >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;
}

void print()
{
cout << item.isbn() << " " << item.units_sold << " "
   << item.revenue << " " << item.avg_price();
}
```

(item.isbn() is a function that returns the book's ISBN)

Of course, I'm not an experienced programmed and they are, so there must be a reason behind the extra complexity, or just that my way is bad programming practice. What do you think?

(Keep in mind that in both my and the book's code, correct use of headers and declarations/definitions is assumed.)

Comment: This one works with console IO, files, string streams, other IO (like Boost ASIO).

Comment: But in your second example, where does `item` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from the book works with `ostream`, `ofstream`, etc., so you can use with `cout` as well as any open files.

A *better* way might be to implement at operator<< and operator>>, so you could use that syntax directly with your objects.

On the other hand, your example works only with `cin` and `cout`, so if you decide you need to output to a file, you need to change your implementation or add another function to do so.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking strictly console IO. It seems like the book's way is generalized IO! Thank you!